# IntegrityError in database stored vlaues in django?

Tags: django, database, django-database, django-database-functions

'''

My problem is  database values can't stored properly 
In below I uploded views functions file,model file as an images. so in model there are three fields but database stored only image stored and other vlaues strored by default get null values so can you help to solving my problem..

'''

userproblem.html

```
<form method="POST" action="/uploadoc/" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-toggle="validator">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <div id="progressbarwizard">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-pills bg-light nav-justified form-wizard-header mb-3">
                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                            <a href="#account-2" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link rounded-0 pt-2 pb-2">
                                                <i class="mdi mdi-account-circle mr-1"></i>
                                                <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Query Form</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>

                                    </ul>

                                    <div class="tab-content b-0 mb-0">
                                        <div class="tab-pane" id="account-2">
                                             <div class="row">
                                                 <div class="col-md-5">
                                                     <label class="col-md-12 col-form-label">Query Types:
                                                    <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-validate="true"  name="queryn" placeholder="Enter Query Types">
                                                        </div>
                                             </div>
                                                 <div class="col-md-5">
                                                     <label class="col-md-12 col-form-label">Description of Query:
                                                    <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                                            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" data-validate="true"  name="querydec" placeholder="Description of Query"></textarea>
                                                        </div>
                                                 </div>

                                            </div><!-- /.First row end --><br>
                                             <div class="row">

                                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                                    <label for="Emailadrress" class="col-md-12 col-form-label">Upload Your File:
                                                    <span class="text-danger"></span></label>
                                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                                                  <input type="file" id="img" name="img" accept="image/*">

                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <label for="Emailadrress" class="col-md-12 col-form-label">Solutions:
                                                    <span class="text-danger"></span></label>
                                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                                            <textarea type="text"   name="querysol" placeholder="Solutions of Query"></textarea>

                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div> <!-- /.second row end -->

                                        </div><br>


                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-12">
                                                    <div class="text-center">
                                                        <div class="mb-3">
                                                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck3">
                                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                                                  <i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> Submit
                                                                </button>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div> <!-- end col -->

                                        </div>

                                    </div>                                    </div> 
                            </form>
```

'[This is error and views function  file [my model images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM095.png)page[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akS49.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set `c` variable from `userProblemModel` named POSTed data in your `uploadoc` view.

```py
c = request.POST.get('userProblemModel')
```

But in your form in html side there is no `userProblemModel` named input tag. That is why you are getting `None` value in `c` variable.

Comment: And i am trying to get data from my userProblemModel that why i am writing

Comment: are you aware of `request.POST` contains data sent from html ?